# Как правильно обновить базу данных?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

В первой версии приложения была копирована для работы приложения из `assets` база данных, с множеством таблиц для чтения, в которую я также добавил свою одну таблицу для постоянного редактирования. Сейчас считаю это ошибкой, лучше бы в отдельном файле базы данных сделал её. Теперь, во второй версии приложения, необходимо частично обновить таблицы для чтения.

Как это лучше сделать?

Есть две идеи:

1. - Отредактировать базу данных из `assets`(таблицы для чтения)
   - Обновить базу данных приложения(каждое поле отдельно)
2. - Отредактировать базу данных из `assets`(таблицы для чтения)
   - Скопировать таблицы для чтения из `assets` в базу данных приложения, оставив одну таблицу для редактирования

Второй пункт думаю лучше будет, но получится ли его реализовать?

Или таблицу(для редактирования) занести в память, удалить старую базу данных, скопировать новую и создать еще одну базу данных с таблицей для редактирования?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что использовался `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov верно

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Стандартный механизм для обновление БД предусмотренный системой это наследование от `SQLiteOpenHelper` и реализация метода [SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)).

`onUpgrade` принимает 2 параметра, предыдущая версия БД и новая версия, в зависимости от них необходимо будет в методе `onUpgrade()` реализовать ветвление и провести внутри вызов SQL инструкции `ALTER TABLE` или если все совсем плохо (модификации очень большие), то завести еще одну промежуточную табличку с помощью которой провести апгрейд БД.

Начальные данные для обновляемых данных конечно же лучше положить опять в `asset`

**P.S.** Версия БД задается в конструкторе хелпера и обычно задается просто константой в коде.

Comment: а для чего использовать промежуточную таблицу если изменения большие?

Comment: Если изменения большие, например затрагивается первичный ключ или удалется много полей, то `Alter Table` не поможет, тогда придется создавать новую таблицу туда копировать из старой и все такое

Answer (score 5):

Получится. Sqlite умеет работать с базой из нескольких файлов. Посмотрите ответ из [этого обсуждения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24080526/2573029).