# Ошибка SQLiteException: no such table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Не могу понять почему не создается таблица в Базе данных, вроде бы все делаю правильно, но получаю ошибку `SQLiteException: no such table.`

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        DBH dbh = new DBH(this);

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        String commentsDoc = etDocumentComment.getText().toString();
        dateExec=dateExsecution.getText().toString();
        String docStatus ="";

        cv.put(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.OUTLET, outletName);
        cv.put(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.DOC_TYPE, documentTypeName);
        cv.put(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.DATE_EXEC, dateExec);
        cv.put(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.MARK, documentMarkName);
        cv.put(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.STATUS, docStatus);
        cv.put(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.COMMENTS, commentsDoc);

        long rowID = db.insert(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
//приложение падает в этой строчке
        Cursor c = db.query(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.CLAIM_WORK_ID);
            int nameColIndexO = c.getColumnIndex(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.OUTLET);
            int nameColIndexD = c.getColumnIndex(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.DOC_TYPE);
            int nameColIndexDE = c.getColumnIndex(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.DATE_EXEC);
            int nameColIndexM = c.getColumnIndex(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.MARK);
            int nameColIndexS = c.getColumnIndex(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.STATUS);
            int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.COMMENTS);


            do {
                Log.d("DAtabase",
                        "ID = " + c.getInt(idColIndex) +
                                ", outlet = " + c.getString(nameColIndexO)+
                                ", doc_type = " + c.getString(nameColIndexD)+
                                ", date_exec = " + c.getString(nameColIndexDE)+
                                ", doc_mark = " + c.getString(nameColIndexM)+
                                ", doc_status = " + c.getString(nameColIndexS)+
                                ", comment = " + c.getString(nameColIndex)
                                );
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else
            Log.d("Nothing in DB", "0 rows");
        c.close();

        return true;
    }
```

Код класса DBHelper:

```
public class DBH extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {
    private static DBH instance = null;
    public final static int VERSION = 13;

    private String mDbName;


    public DBH(Context context) {
        super(context, context.getString(R.string.db_name), null, VERSION);
        this.mDbName = context.getString(R.string.db_name);
    }


    public static DBH getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBH(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

  @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        if (!checkDataBase()) {
            createTables(db);
        }
    }

public final static class ClaimWorkInfo {
        public final static String TABLE_NAME = "claim_work";

        public final static class DC {
            public final static String CLAIM_WORK_ID = "claim_work_id";
            public final static String OUTLET = "outlet";
            public final static String DOC_TYPE = "doc_type";
            public final static String DATE_EXEC = "text";
            public final static String MARK = "mark";
            public final static String STATUS = "status";
            public final static String COMMENTS = "comments";
        }

        public final static class DT {
            public final static String CLAIM_WORK_ID = "integer primary key autoincrement";
            public final static String OUTLET = "text";
            public final static String DOC_TYPE = "text";
            public final static String DATE_EXEC = "text";
            public final static String MARK = "text";
            public final static String COMMENTS = "text";
            public final static String Status = "text";

        }
    }
private boolean isTableExists(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {
        if (tableName == null || db == null || !db.isOpen()) {
            return false;
        }

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='" + tableName + "'", null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int count = cursor.getInt(0);
                cursor.close();
                return count > 0;
            } else {
                cursor.close();
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    private void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName, Field[] flds, Field[] tps, String foreign) {
        if (!isTableExists(db, tableName)) {
            AppLog.e("Create table: " + "!isTableExists" + tableName);
            String sql = "create table " + tableName + " (";

            for (int i = 0; i < flds.length; i++) {

                try {
                    sql = sql + flds[i].get(DBH.class).toString() + " " + tps[i].get(DBH.class).toString();
                    if (i != flds.length - 1) {
                        sql = sql + ", ";
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    AppLog.e("Create table error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            sql = sql + (foreign == null ? ")" : (", " + foreign + ")"));
            AppLog.i("Query table creation: " + sql);

            try {
                db.execSQL(sql);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                AppLog.e("Create table error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
private void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
createTable(db, DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.TABLE_NAME, DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DC.class.getFields(), DBH.ClaimWorkInfo.DT.class.getFields(), null);
    }
 private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mDbName, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return (checkDB != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: локализуйте исключение после no such table много что написано, да и как минимум строчка откуда выбрасывается это же логично...
А пока всё ясно, у вас нет таблицы по которой идет запрос определенного вида

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашла проблему, база данных уже была создана в этом приложение, следовательно при создании объекта класса DBHelper (DBH), метод onCreate(), в котором должны создаваться таблицы не отрабатовал. Удалила приложение и установила его заново, все заработало.

Comment: Для внесения изменений в структуру БД [используется метод `onUpgrade()`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459778/177345) класса-наследника  `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Чтобы метод был вызван, версия БД должна быть увеличена. Это в основном актуально, когда приложение уже используется пользователями. На этапе создания\отладки конечно проще переустановить приложение.