# Не добавляется колонка в БД

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

Посадили рефакторить приложение, которое обменивается информацией через API с сервером.
На данный момент надо добавить спиннер "область". Данные областей находятся на сервере. 
Добавил все данные, описал связь с API, но выдает ошибку 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: StatesId (code 1):.
На локальной БД есть это поле, на сервере тоже добавили.

Есть пару вопросов:

1. Могу ли я посмотреть в android studio БД?(кроме папки assets, там есть данное поле) Ведь, видимо, есть ещё одна БД, какая связывается с сервером.

2. Если ли у вас варианты решения данной проблемы конкретно под мой случай.

Comment: Скорей всего вы просто добавили это поле  скрипт создания бд, но если бд уже существует на устройствах, то метод ```onCreate()``` не будет вызываться. Для этого вам надо писать способ обновления бд в методе ```onUpgrade()``` и повышать версию БД для того, чтобы он был вызван.

Comment: По [проблеме](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552177/177345) с БД. По второму - непосредственно в Android Studio посмотреть БД нельзя, но [есть варианты](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428785/177345)

Comment: Приложение не в продакшене. Я его доделываю. <br>
Думал, что onUpgrade() используется только, когда приложение в продакшене и надо повышать версию. Или я не прав?

Comment: Ну тогда просто удалите и заново установите приложение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решил проблему.** Надо было переустановить приложение, внести правки в БД(через sqliteStudio, к примеру) и настроить парсинг данных, который сервер мне отсылает.
Всем спасибо за помощь)